# nca_connect_server: cannot communicate with host in LoadRunner 12.53

Tags: oracle, loadrunner

I'm currently testing HP LoadRunner 12.53 with Oracle EBS R12.2.5.
I created a simple script using both Oracle Apps, and Oracle NCA + Http protocol (Log in, bring up a form and close/log out) and replayed but run into below error. (same error for both scripts)

**nca_connect_server: cannot communicate with host**

icx_ticket is correlated and works OK as it is picked and replaced in the parameter.

No need to correlate JSessionIDForms as EBS is running on socket mode.

It is s just simple script with single correlation but can't find any clue for the error.

What could be the root cause of the error?
Where should I look at for a clue? How to make the error / log more verbose and detailed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Record it twice.  If the value shifts, then correlate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have properly set up the environment before recording, Below steps need to be taken for setting up the environment

**1.Set "record = names" flag for specific user profile in Oracle EBS** Application** via administrator login  (search google how to achieve this or simply ask your application team to do it for you)

**2.Run Time Settings and Default.cfg file changes**
Run Time Settings
Keep the below values to high limit to avoid replay timeout errors

- Run-Time Settings > Internet Protocol >Preferences > Options>
- Step Download Limit
- HTTP-request connect timeout:
- HTTP-receive receive timeout:
- Keep-Alive timeout:
- Run-Time Settings >Browser>Browser Emulation>
- 1)   Simulate a new user on each iteration – checked

**3. default.cfg file inside script directory**

```
"RelativeURL={NCAJServSessionId}" statement  in the default.cfg file rolls back each time we run the script so we need to check that it is
```

- /forms/lservlet;JsessionIDForms={NCAJServSessionId} -- R12 Version or
- /forms/formservlet?JServSessionIdforms={NCAJServSessionId}  -- EBS 11
  i Version

**4. Correlation - Last but not the least**

Ensure correct correlation of each and every parameter, The best way to achieve this is by recording the script 2 times and comparing them using a suitable tool, Correlate each value which might be changing each time you replay the script

Note :- The Oracle EBS is not fully supported by Loadrunner please download the loadrunner compatability matrix and check if your version is supported by Loadrunner.